# Having a problem displaying data from last inserted data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a staff rota planner....have three tables Staff (Staff details), Event (Event details), and Job (JobId, JobDate, EventId (fk), StaffId (fk)). I need to display the last inserted job detail with the staff name. I've been at it for couple of hours and getting nowhere. Thanks for the help in advance. My code is the following:

```
$eventId = $_POST['eventid'];
$selectBox = $_POST['selectbox'];
$timePeriod = $_POST['time'];
$selectedDate = $_POST['date'];
$count = count($selectBox);

echo "<fieldset><center>";
echo "<form name=submit action='' method=post>";

//display the selected event
$eventsql = "SELECT EventName FROM Event WHERE EventId= ".$eventId;
$result = mysql_query($eventsql);

while ($eventarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $eventName = $eventarray['EventName'];
    echo "<h3><font color=red>".$eventName." </font></h3>"; 
}

//constructing the staff selection  
if (empty($selectBox))
{
    echo "<p>You didn't select any member of staff to be assigned.";
    echo "<p><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1)'>";
} else
    {
        echo "<p> You selected ".$count. " staff for this show.";

        for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
        {
            $selectId[$i] = $selectBox[$i];

            //insert the details into the Job table in the database
            $insertJob = "INSERT INTO Job (JobDate, TimePeriod, EventId, StaffId) 
                            VALUES ('".$selectedDate."', '".$timePeriod."', ".$eventId.", 
                            ".$selectId[$i].")";
            $exeinsertJob = mysql_query($insertJob) or die (mysql_error());


        }
    }   

    //display the staff details (last inserted) assigned to the job
    $insertedlist = "SELECT Staff.LastName, Staff.FirstName, Job.JobDate, Job.TimePeriod
                        FROM Staff, Job
                        WHERE Job.StaffId = Staff.StaffId
                        AND Job.JobDate = ".$selectedDate;
    $exeinsertedlist = mysql_query($insertedlist) or die (mysql_error());

    if ($exeinsertedlist) 
    {
        echo "<p><table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='3'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name </th><th>Date</th><th>Hours</th></tr>";

        while ($joblistarray = mysql_fetch_array($exeinsertedlist))
                {                   
                echo "<tr><td align=center>".$joblistarray['LastName']."
                    </td><td align=center>".$joblistarray['FirstName']."
                    </td><td align=center>".$joblistarray['JobDate']."
                    </td><td align=center>".$joblistarray['TimePeriod']."</td></tr>";
                }

            echo "</table>";

            echo "<h3><a href=AssignStaff.php>Add More Staff?</a></h3>";
        }
        else {
                    echo "The Job list can not be displayed at this time. Try again.";
                    echo "<p><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1)'>";
                }




echo "</center>";   
echo "</fieldset>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection be carefull. And SQL + business + html in the same place is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mysql_inserted_id to get the last inserted job id.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. mysql_insert_id() only returns the last inserted id. I need to display data on multiple inserts. I'm creating a rota and when assigning 2 or more staff to an event, need to display all the staff details that have just been assigned. I have edited some of the code above to make it more clearer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues to look at:

- Looks like your `Job.JobDate` value may need to be enclosed by quotes in the `insertedlist` query (unless this is a timestamp).
- Where are you setting the `$eventname` variable?

Comment: Thanks Dieseltime! I've edited the code but still not getting the right answer. JobDate is a date selected by the user and is a date data type in the table.